# Can I have emacs show me the definition of a function?

Tags: c, emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I best do source code browsing inside emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071919/how-can-i-best-do-source-code-browsing-inside-emacs)

I have a large base to modify, and I want to be able to follow a function to its definition, the better to read it. Can I do this in emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use [etags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html). It will take you to the definition of any symbol. [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) is a cheat sheet full of commands for it. You'll have to generate a TAGS file using the `etags` program first. I use this on a mixed C/Ada codebase:

```
(find . -name '*.[ch]'
 find . -name '*.ad[bs]'
)|grep -v "CVS/Base" | sort | xargs etags -a
```