# open include files in emacs as you can in msvc (visual c++)

Tags: visual-c++, emacs, ide, include

MSVC visual c++ allows you to right click on an #include directive header file (.h) and select to "open document".
This makes browsing source code a breeze as it turns an entire source code tree basically into a hyperlinked website. 
Is this convenience available with emacs? Is there another apparatus that allows browsing source code, any code you write, any project create, so automatically? Does Xcode have it? Does eclipse? Does anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>, which runs the command [`ff-find-other-file`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/find-file.el), is what you are looking for.  It will open the included file when the point is on the `#include` line.

Googling for `emacs code browsing` also reveals

- [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) ([Emacs Code Browser](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsCodeBrowser))
- [How can I best do source code browsing inside Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4071919/850781)
- [code browsing, refactoring, auto completion in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671412/850781)

Comment: Yes. And Xcode has open "callee/caller" and vim has something called typing gd but cedet is applicable to it. And eclipse has 'open declarations' and code::blocks has 'open header file'. I think MSVC and windows are going to be clicked into the trash bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [semantic Smart Jump](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/semantic/Smart-Jump.html#Smart-Jump), move the cursor to the #include line, then execute command `semantic-ia-fast-jump`, this command is usually used to jump to symbols, it can also jump to include file.

As a precondition to use `semantic-ia-fast-jump`, you need manage you code in an [ede project](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ede/ede_002dcpp_002droot.html), here is an example for C/C++ project

suppose your directory structure like this:

```
~/myproject/
  |-include/test.h
  |-src/test.c
  |-Makefile
```

and your ede project configuration

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "MyProject"
    :file "~/myproject/Makefile"
    :include-path '( "/include" )
    :system-include-path '( "/usr/include/mysql/" )
```

test.c

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include "test.h"
```

Now, move your cursor to either of the two line in test.c, run `semantic-ia-fast-jump`